# Coldfusion EntityLoad reading calculated field

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018

I have an Entity with a lot of fields.

```
<cfscript>
component persistent="true" output="false" {
...
property name="placeholder"     default = 0;
property name="expired"         update=false    insert=false;
property name="admin"           default = 0;
property name="partner"         default = 0;
```

Much later, but in the same request. I am going to do this

```
if (!arguments.Account.getPlaceholder() )   local.arRoles.append("account");
if (!arguments.Account.getExpired()     )   local.arRoles.append("event");
if (arguments.Account.getAdmin()        )   local.arRoles.append("admin");
if (arguments.Account.getPartner()      )   local.arRoles.append("partner");
```

And I get an error that looks like this

[image]

I do a dump of the object. It looks like it should be OK

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expired is not like the other fields. It is backed by a calculation done on the database. That is why it is

```
 property name="expired"            update=false    insert=false;
```

Furthermore

```
 Account = EntityLoadByPK("Accounts", arguments.id);
```

Many not have what is expected. A read from the DB must be forced

```
 Account = EntityLoadByPK("Accounts", arguments.id);
 EntityReload(Account);
```